# Split Position in HorizontalSplitPanel in GWT

Tags: gwt, split, panel

I am trying to make an animated split panel in GWT, where the splitting can also be done by dragging the splitter. So to initiate the animation I need to know the current split position of the split panel. But I could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but isn't "dragging the splitter" inside a SplitPanel automatically going to result in the panels being resized?
You might be able to determine the position by checking the position of the leftwidget (getLeftWidget().getWidth()) and adding the half of the splitters-width to it (I think it's 8px in width - so 4px).
I am not sure if there's any better way to determine the splitter as the HorizontalSplitPanel is a final class and you can't really access the splitter inside it directly.

I might be wrong though, but it's what I just figured out (since I am messing around with this HorizontalSplitPanel, which sadly seems to have broken for Internet Explorer 8).